# Error message trying to compile a QT program on OSX: Trace/BPT trap: 5

Tags: c++, macos, qt, compiler-errors, osx-mavericks

Attempting to compile a program on OSX Maverick, using QTCreator, I get the following error:

```
:-1: error: [ui_mainwindow.h] Trace/BPT trap: 5.
```

QT was working fine before I had to reinstall the OS and I didn't remember doing anything different this time. What this could mean?

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using?

Comment: Just got this exact error, Qt 5.3 OSX 10.9.4